# Books on advanced real analysis topics/metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces

There is a class in my uni called Real Analysis, which comes after 3 semesters of "analysis" and 1 semester of complex analysis. I am looking for good books that cover the material, but most of the books I can find are either more basic and cover mostly material that we learned in previous classes or too specialized and intended for graduate students.

Here's some of the topics covered by the class to be more specific:
Peano axioms, Properties of real and natural numbers, Dedekind cuts, metric space definitions, examples and metrics in vector spaces defined by norms, open and closed subsets of metric spaces, equivalent metrics, countable and uncountable sets, Zorn lemma, metric space completeness, Baire theorem, C[a, b] spaces, Arzela theorem, products of metric spaces, Cantor set etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Topology of Metric Spaces* by S. Kumaresan

*Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by W. Rudin

*Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces* by J. Heinonen

*Introductory Real Analysis* by Kolmogorov and Fomin

*Metric Spaces* by E. T. Copson

*Metric Spaces* by M. O'Searcoid

*Understanding Anlaysis* by S. Abott

Comment: Nice, although I've already checked Rudin and it doesn't cover most of the topics I need. The Kolmogorov book looks interesting, and it looks like it's pretty cheap on Amazon too.